# как работает вывод в консоль (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, terminal

Всем привет. Сейчас задам весьма тривиальный вопрос: как работает вывод в консоль? Я вот использую nodejs как пример.

Простой участок кода:

`console.log(1);
console.log(2);
console.error(3);
console.log(4);`

А теперь внимание:
Если запускать через терминал (в линуксе) `node test.js`
выведет все по порядку: 1 2 3 4

Но если запускать в какой-ниб среде, которая умеет отличить ошибку от инфо... таких как шторм или ci...

[image: вывод ошибок в шторме]

То будет все что угодно, 3 1 2 4, 1 3 2 4 или 1 2 4 3. По настроению цифра 3 будет в любом месте лога.

А изначально, почему у меня этот вопрос возник, это ci:

[image: вывод ошибок в ci]

Ошибки смешиваются с логами.

**Как это работает?** Ответ напрашивается такой: мол есть очередь сообщений, а ошибки лезут в не очереди. При условии что терминал может отличить ошибку от сообщения.

А теперь я хочу пруфы. Почему так сделали? На самом деле все так обстоит? что оптимизировали? Почему не по порядку... Или все таки nodejs виноват?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти два способа вывода пишут в **разные потоки вывода**.

`console.log` пишет в `stdout` (файловый дескриптор 1).
`console.error` пишет в `stderr` (файловый дескриптор 2).

Если какой-то обработчик этих двух потоков задумает их выводить комбинированно (в ваших случаях именно так), то результат будет зависеть от способа комбинации. Это уже в зоне ответственности не Node.js, а процесса, который его запускает. Шелла, CI-раннера или чего-то ещё.

Можно точно рассчитывать, что порядок в пределах каждого отдельно взятого потока порядок выводимых строк сохранится. Для логов потоки и вовсе обычно выводят в отдельные файлы.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно! Не могу репу повысить, поэтому просто Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @АндрейСорока вы можете отметить ответ галочкой, если он отвечает на ваш вопрос. Спасибо!